# 80s-90s movie about teenage alien boys landing on earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, spaceship

I watched this movie in the early to mid 90s about a small group of teenage like alien boys that landed, possibly due to a tech issue or even crash landing, on earth. They were found by some younger kiddos. One was a little girl.

The alien boys had a very surfer, hippie tone of voice and personality. Super radical type of teen behavior. I can't remember much from the movie itself but the young kids helped the alien boys fix their ship and got them off the planet before they were taken in by the government I believe.

Before they took off, I remember the little girl crying and one of the alien boys telling her not to cry yadayada.

Think, ninja turtle attitudes and real Micheal Jackson thriller style type of spacesuit.

These are shots in the dark memories. First thought everyone thinks of is [Explorers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089114/) but that is not it. Not the same aliens or story line. The kids in this movie do not build the ship at all. They don't go to outer space.

These teen alien boys come here and need the kids' help getting home. There is a little girl helping them too. Someone has to know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Reminiscent of Earth Girls are Easy.

Comment: Are [these](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-RpxHczcT7Q/maxresdefault.jpg) your aliens?

Comment: [*They Came from Outer Space*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80AcZm3aLSc) was a TV show, and doesn't seem as Totally Radical, but mentioning it.

Answer (score 5):

### Could be *[Spaced Invaders](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100666/)* (1990)?

In this film, the aliens are Martians - classic little green men - forced to take part in a space war with the Arcturans by an enforcer drone aboard their spaceship. Flying near Earth on Halloween, they pick up a re-broadcast of Orson Welles’ *The War of the Worlds* and think the Martian invasion is real, so the drone forces them to participate and they land in a rural American town.

Most humans they meet assume they’re kids in fancy costumes, but they are discovered by the local sheriff and his daughter Kathy, a little girl played by a pre-*Jurassic Park* Ariana Richards, who eventually realise they’re kind of harmless and help them return to space.

There’s sort of a gang of kids - it’s mostly about Kathy, who’s new in town, and the aliens themselves, who kind of fulfil that role. The Martians aren’t kids but they sure behave like goofy teenagers, and some of them have personalities matching what you describe. Kathy does have a couple of trick or treating friends, though, including one kid dressed as a duck. The Martians don’t so much crash as park very badly, though they do damage their ship. The drone also forces them to stay to carry out what it thinks is their mission, and their hyperdrive threatens to melt down near the climax of the film. And there’s definitely a farewell similar to the one you describe, though Kathy consoles the tiny scout robot the Martians bring with them, as well as (or maybe instead of) them consoling her.

So I think it seems a pretty good fit. It’s not seen as a *great* film but I loved it as a kid and it has some really interesting quirks that have earned it a bit of a cult following.

[image: Spaced Invaders]

Comment: Thanks for adding the photo, @DoscoJones!

Comment: After their hard landing: "Well, let's see. We got a torqued-out digi-framus, our mega-spaz redundancy pile is on the blink, and it looks like we bruised our boo-boo."

Comment: @DoscoJones ah - fair enough. I’ll revise the answer, thanks again!